# Start emacs with Global TODO list along with default org file

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, start-up, todo

How can I open the global `TODO` list along side my default Org file.

Even with Desktop Save mode is on, whenever I open Emacs, only the org file reopens, and not the buffer with the global `TODO` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like the following code at the end of your init file:

```el
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
(find-file "/path/to/my/default.org")
(org-agenda nil "t")
```

I had to inhibit the splash screen, otherwise it hid the global TODO list.

Comment: Thanks! I had duplicated init files, now it works.